# How can i change the direction of a div element without changing the body

Tags: html, css

Hello i was trying to change the direction of a div element (from ltr to rtl) in order to show perfectly with the Arabic language but i didnt know how so this is the code please help

```html
<div>
    <section id="func1">
      <label for="function"> :دستور الدالة 1 </label>
      <input id="function" type="text" value="x*x" onchange="plot();">
      <p></p>
      <label for="derivative"> :مشتق الدالة 1 </label>
      <input type=text id="der" value="2*x" onchange="plot();">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <label for="color">:لون المنحنى </label>  <input type=color id="color" onchange="plot();">
      <p></p>
    </section>
</div>
```

also this is a picture to describe more:
[image: The input field should appear at the left and the text at the right]

The input field should appear at the left and the text at the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put a `dir` attribute with the value of `rtl`, like this:  `dir="rtl"`

Check the snippet:

```html
<div dir="rtl">
    <section id="func1">
      <label for="function"> :دستور الدالة 1 </label>
      <input id="function" type="text" value="x*x" onchange="plot();">
      <p></p>
      <label for="derivative"> :مشتق الدالة 1 </label>
      <input type=text id="der" value="2*x" onchange="plot();">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <label for="color">:لون المنحنى </label>  <input type=color id="color" onchange="plot();">
      <p></p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the text flow direction by using the CSS property `direction: rtl` (cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction), like this:

```css
div {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section id="func1">
    <label for="function"> :دستور الدالة 1 </label>
    <input id="function" type="text" value="x*x" onchange="plot();">
    <p></p>
    <label for="derivative"> :مشتق الدالة 1 </label>
    <input type=text id="der" value="2*x" onchange="plot();">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <label for="color">:لون المنحنى </label> <input type=color id="color" onchange="plot();">
    <p></p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use Direction in a three ways i.e `ltr` , `rtl` and `auto`

**Syntax**

```
<element dir="ltr|rtl|auto">
```

```css
.direction{
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="direction">
  <section id="func1">
    <label for="function"> :دستور الدالة 1 </label>
    <input id="function" type="text" value="x*x" onchange="plot();">
    <p></p>
    <label for="derivative"> :مشتق الدالة 1 </label>
    <input type=text id="der" value="2*x" onchange="plot();">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <label for="color">:لون المنحنى </label> <input type=color id="color" onchange="plot();">
    <p></p>
  </section>
</div>
```

1. ltr - Default. Left-to-right text direction
2. rtl - Right-to-left text direction
3. auto - Let the browser figure out the text direction, based on the content (only recommended if the text direction is unknown)

checkout more documentation about Direction [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp)